# jQuery - Need two elements to use the same jQuery function but have separate results

Tags: jquery, html

I made some jQuery that limits the character count in text fields. It works just fine, but any optimizations are welcomed. Now my issue is that if I want to apply this to multiple text fields, there is a conflict. The conflict is that when 1 character is entered into any text field, it affects all of the text fields specified in the jQuery.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vrhkkat/)

**jQuery**

```
    function countChar(val) {
        var allowed_length = 20; // character count limit here
        var len = val.value.length;
        if (len >= allowed_length) {
            val.value = val.value.substring(0, allowed_length);
            jQuery('.chars-twenty').text(0);
        } else {
            jQuery('.chars-twenty').text(allowed_length - len);
        }
    }


    countChar(jQuery('#demo1').get(0));
    jQuery('#demo1').keyup(function() {
        countChar(this);
    })

    countChar(jQuery('#demo2').get(0));
            jQuery('#demo2').keyup(function() {
        countChar(this);
    })
```

I need the specific textarea character counts to act completely separate from one another.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clean, but you could search for the class name in the prev() elements:

```
    function countChar(val) {
        var allowed_length = 20; // character count limit here
        var len = val.value.length;
        if (len >= allowed_length) {
            val.value = val.value.substring(0, allowed_length);
            // Notice the change here:
            jQuery(val).prev().find(".chars-twenty").text(0);
        } else {
            // And here.
            jQuery(val).prev().find(".chars-twenty").text(allowed_length - len);
        }
    }


    countChar(jQuery('#demo1').get(0));
    jQuery('#demo1').keyup(function() {
        countChar(this);
    })

    countChar(jQuery('#demo2').get(0));
    jQuery('#demo2').keyup(function() {
        countChar(this);
    })
```

Here's the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vrhkkat/1/

**Edit:** Here's what I would do instead, assuming you are able to change the HTML.  Add a `data` attribute to the span to associate it with the particular textarea.  This enables you to be sure of targeting the correct span, even if your DOM changes.

```
<span class="chars-twenty" data-textarea="demo1">
```

And then access the correct span using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(".chars-twenty[data-textarea="+val.id+"]").text('...');
```

An example in another Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vrhkkat/2/

Comment: Perfect Jonathan, this works for me. [Got rid of a line of code too.](http://jsfiddle.net/6vrhkkat/3/) Thanks for the help!
EDIT: I used your second suggestion, in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on on what browsers you need to support, you might be able to simply use the `maxlength` property. It is supported on Chrome, IE 10+, Firefox 4+, Opera 15+ and Safari.

```
<textarea rows="3" id="demo1" maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: I want it to display the visual character count meter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxLen = 20; // character count limit here

function countChar(jqObj) {
    var len = jqObj.val().length;
    var diff = maxLen - len;

    if (len > maxLen) {
        len = maxLen;
        diff = 0;
    }

    jqObj.val(jqObj.val().substr(0, len)).prev('p').find('span.chars-twenty').text(diff);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id*='demo']").keyup(function () {
        countChar($(this));
    }).each(function () {
        countChar($(this));
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EricLease/73mw32jk/) forked and modified from OPs.